# vim: disable mswin (turn off windows shortcut keys)

Tags: windows, vim

I just installed vim on Windows XP machine. When logged on to another user a little bit ago, I went to `C:\program files\vim\_vimrc`  and commented out the following lines

```
"source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
"source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
"behave mswin
```

and then Ctrl-X didn't cut text -- which is good.

However, when I logged in as administrator on the computer and run vim, Ctrl-X went back to cutting text :(. I even renamed `C:\program files\vim\vim72\mswin.vim` to `C:\program files\vim\vim72\mswin.nouse.vim` and the silly Windows shortcuts are still in effect.

Where can I fix this? can I put `behave nomswin` in my ~/.vimrc file to undo those shortcuts?

EDIT: Even logging in as original user now vim uses windows shortcuts.

EDIT: fixed typo in pathname

EDIT: The following are VIM and VIMRUNTIME

> echo %VIM%
>   C:\Program Files\Vim
>
> echo %VIMRUNTIME%
>   C:\Program Files\Vim\vim72

Comment: Note: `mswin.vim` explicitly remaps `<C-[XCV]>`, so if you've already loaded the default Windows `.vimrc`, you (unfortunately) can't turn off the Windows-y settings with a simple `behave xterm`; instead, you must explicitly `unmap` the offending mappings. (This is a comment instead of an answer since it doesn't seem to address your particular question, which is how to avoid loading the offending `.vimrc` file in the first place.)

Answer (score 3):

Your vim installation is really odd when I look at the pathnames you gave.

The usual paths are: $VIM = `C:\Program Files\vim` and $VIMRUNTIME=`C:\Program Files\vim\vim{versionnumber}`. (I set neither of these variable)

The default vimrc are `$VIM/vimrc` and `$VIMRC/_vimrc` (which I delete both/don't install), and each user is meant to have its own `$HOME/_vimrc` (not `$HOME/.vimrc`) (see `:version`)

PS: In case you have installed vim several times (vim 7.1, vim 7.2, cygwin-vim, ...) you may have to check the value of $VIM and $VIMRUNTIME to know what you are really executing.

Comment: oops, those pathnames were a typo. I just fixed them.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, reading the `:version` output and chasing the config files, `mswin.win` on Vim 8.2 starts with:

```
if exists("g:skip_loading_mswin") && g:skip_loading_mswin
  finish
endif
```

Thus, I added

```
let g:skip_loading_mswin=1
```

to `~/_vimrc` and problem solved.

Comment: Was thinking about why it doesn't work for me now. Found this answer and then, having searched with another query, found my own question with a similar answer https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/16714/10514 . Yours is certainly more elaborate. But in my case, the problem was in another place...

Answer (score 2):

## Windows Terminal

It catches and handles <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and similar key combinations before they get to Vim.

Go to *Settings*,
then *Actions* and
remove <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> from *Copy text*
and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> from *Paste*.